# Custom Web Parts

Tags: web-part, custom

I'm a designer and I'm kind of new to Sharepoint. I designed this mockup for an Women's group at my company, but before developers were able to start implementing the design, they were pulled to another project. Now I'm trying to figure out how to turn these 7 sections into functioning apps. Does anybody have suggestions of web parts that could be used to achieve this look?

[image: Sharepoint mockup]

Comment: What version of SharePoint? On-prem or Office 365? Do you want to _develop_ the Web parts or only use existing/third-part Web part?